# При запуске JSP из Eclipse на Tomcat 9.0 сообщает о занятых портах

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, port

При запуске Tomcat в Eclipse все происходит нормально.
Когда пытаюсь запустить JSP файл выскакивает ошибка

> Several ports (8008, 8084, 8012) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Да, я знаю что надо поменять порты. Да я их менял. Каждый раз после этого ошибка выскакивает та же что и в прошлый раз с изменением только номера портов что выставил.

Как это исправить? Как бы других проектов не запущено и по моему ну нечему занимать ново-выставленные порты.

Comment: может быть инстанс томката некорректно выключается и он в фоне продолжает работать?

Comment: или порты заблокированы фаерволом или антивирусом?